# Como pegar o valor ng-value de checkbox no AngularJS/Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic

Imaginem uma aplicação tradicional no AngularJS

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    <input type="input" ng-model="resultado">
    Resultado: {{resultado}}<br>


Resultado {{escolha}}

</body>
</html>
```

Agora, imaginem que eu quero fazer dataBind contidos no ng-value de uma checkbox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="escolha" ng-value="google">google<BR>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="escolha" ng-value="yahoo">yahoo<BR>
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="escolha" ng-value="microsoft">microsoft<BR>

Resultado {{escolha}}

</body>
</html>
```

Também gostaria de saber se é possível fazer com radio no padrão IONIC

```
<ion-radio ng-model="escolha" ng-value="'A'">google.com</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="escolha" ng-value="'B'">yahoo.com</ion-radio>
<ion-radio ng-model="escolha" ng-value="'C'">microsoft.com</ion-radio>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coloquei abaixo um exemplo do [`radio`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bradio%5D) usando `AngularJS` para que você tome como exemplo. Você só precisa vincular o `ng-model` com a variável que deseja atribuir valor. Notei que você descreve o comportamento de um `radio` e não de um `check`, afinal precisa apenas de um valor.

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('CheckController', CheckController);

function CheckController() {
  var vm = this;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CheckController as vm">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" value="A"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" value="B"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" value="C"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" value="D"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" value="E"/>

  <br>
  <br>

  Opção escolhida: {{vm.opcao}}
</div>
```

No caso você só utilizará `ng-value` se precisar de um valor dinâmico para a opção:

```js
angular
  .module('app', [])
  .controller('CheckController', CheckController);

function CheckController() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.a = 'yahoo';
  vm.b = 'google';
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="CheckController as vm">
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" ng-value="vm.a"/>
  <input type="radio" ng-model="vm.opcao" ng-value="vm.b"/>

  <br>
  <br>

  Opção escolhida: {{vm.opcao}}
</div>
```

Comment: Show de resposta, não tem nem como ter duvida, rs

Comment: Sim, muito bom mesmo!